# How to get css background image url in NodeJS and Express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I came to know we cannot use getComputedStyle in Node environment because that's a browser behavior.

However, I wanted to get all the background image urls in Node and download them
like so

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
Array.from(divs).filter((div) => {
    let backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue("background-image");
```

But I cannot do that.

**How to get all the divs having background-image url as styles in NodeJS?**

Comment: I guess you can post it to `Node.js` API from your frontend. Are you using any template engine?

Answer (score 0):

Use a headless browser like puppeteer to render the webpage. Extract all the information you need from the browser and send it back to Node.js. I think this will help.

Regards,
omi

Answer (score 0):

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const backgroundImages = divs.map(div=>div.style.backgroundImage)
console.log(backgroundImages)
// Output: ['url("https://www.image.com/profil.png")','url("https://www.image.com/profil2.png")']
```